# Waiting for action server when using SimpleActionClient

Tags: ros, simpleactionclient, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my code, I have constructed a SimpleActionClient with the MoveArmAction interface to communicate with move_right_arm action. I have also launched the right_arm_navigation.launch file from pr2_3dnav, but the code does not get past the "move_arm.waitForServer()". It does not throw any errors and the terminal where I launched the right_arm_navigation.launch shows the same "Move arm action started" message before and after I ran my code. I tried reading the debugging messages from the rxconsole, but didnt get very far.
We are currently using Diamondback on our PR2.

Does anyone have/had the same problem?

Thanks,

Nash

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9711/waiting-for-action-server-when-using-simpleactionclient/) by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 207 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just ran across this error - check and make sure that you are specifying the constraint_region_orientation for the PositionConstraint. You need to either give it a valid orientation or if you just want the identity, make sure that constraint_region_orientation.w = 1.0.  By default, ROS quaternion messages are initialized to all 0.0 which is an invalid orientation.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-05-11**:
Thanks!, I had to specify valid constraints for both position and orientation for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried this in diamondback (in the simulator) using the code (in src/move_arm_joint_goal.cpp) in pr2_arm_navigation_tutorials. Are you giving the right argument to the action client - it should be "move_right_arm" if you are addressing the right arm.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The way action client waits for server is by looking at a bunch of ROS topics and trying to get messages on all of them. You can look at the code in the "actionlib" package to see exactly how it is working

```
 roscd actionlib
 cd src/actionlib/
 EDITOR action_client.py
```

That said you should just try

```
 rostopic list | grep <the name of your topic - something about right arm I guess>
```

to see which topics are there (they should be something about status/feedback/result) and then

```
 rostopic echo <topic that you care about>
```

to see whether the topic is published at all.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) with karma: 535 on 2011-04-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks! I had addressed the "move_r_arm" instead.
But now I am encountering another issue, whenever I run the code on the robot, then /environment_server throws an error saying "Unable to transform pose constraint on link 'r_wrist_roll_link' to frame 'odom_combined' " followed by "Could not prepare planning environment"
I also tried listening to /environment_server/collision_pose and /environment_server/state_validity but nothing is published whenever I run the code.
Also I have to re-launch the "right_arm_navigation.launch" file everytime I want to re-run the code because if I run the code again, it does not get past the "move_arm.wait_for_result()"

Any advice?

---

Originally posted by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) with karma: 207 on 2011-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-04-25**:
When you send move_arm a request, check the timestamp and frame_id on the request. The error message indicates that something went wrong in doing the transformation - usually this is because you have not setup the request properly by specifying the right timestamp or the right frame.

**Comment by [Nash](https://answers.ros.org/users/130/nash/) on 2011-04-25**:
No, I am running everything on the PR2.

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-04-25**:
If you are running anything not on the PR2 itself check your ROS_IP variable if it is set to the IP of the laptop/desktop where you are running this.